# Remove `Set as desktop background` option?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, desktop

Using Windows 8.1. If I need to change the desktop, I can right-click the desktop, select `Personalise` then `Desktop Background` in the lower left. This is fine because the background is usually set once and then changed infrequently thereafter.

However, Windows offers the option `Set as desktop background` when you right-click an image file (BMP, PNG, etc).

[image: Set as background image]

Since changing the background is done rarely, this seems overkill. This afternoon I accidentally clicked the option. I'd long since forgotten where the original background image was buried in my file structure (and there is no `Undo`!). After about an hr of searching, I eventually found the file and restored my background.

Can this option be removed from the context menu to prevent future accidents?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Thanks, that question and answer solved my issue. To anyone who comes here: The answer from `Steven Vascellaro` is the one you want. Specifically use `ShellMenuView` (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html)